# Sqlite - conditional SELECT?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table with languages.

I would like to make a query that gets rows with specified language, but if it won't return any data - with default language.

Is this possible to do in one query?

UPDATE:

My table: Language 
Fields:

id - (primary key, unique),

lang - (text, not unique),

content - (text, not unique).

and my current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM Languages WHERE (id='1') AND (lang = 'es')
```

As I mentioned before if above query won't return anything I would like to get results form default language:

```
SELECT * FROM Languages WHERE (id='1') AND (lang = 'en')
```

'en' is default language in this example.

Comment: Could you describe your table? And perhaps add the query that you have now?

Comment: If id is the primary key of the table Languages, your query doesn't make any sense.  It can only ever return a single record.

Comment: Yes, You're right but Table I posted is rather an example. Actual table that I use is more complicated. I used this artificial example table only to provide ground on which I can set real problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(SELECT CASE
    WHEN ((SELECT ID FROM table WHERE language = specified language) IS NULL)
    THEN
      default language
    ELSE
      specified language
    END);
```

It will return your desired language, based on the result of the subquery.  Plug that into the WHERE clause of your final query.

Comment: I don't think that's SQLite syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure the update is SQL syntax at all — CASE usually supplies a scalar value, not a row set.  I'm off to check whether that's SQL that I don't know about.  (If you want to use CASE, I think it could be done in the WHERE part to determine which language to compare against).

Comment: Then you can modify the above query to return a scalar for the language, and then plug that language scalar into the WHERE clause of the query of your choice. See http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2009-06/msg00145.html and my new update.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM lang_tbl
WHERE lang_tbl.name = "search_lang" OR lang_tbl.name = "default_lang"
ORDER BY lang_tbl.name = "search_lang" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Exactly. OP wants to get 'preferred or default' language, this should solve the problem.

Comment: This works only if there is one row to return. In my case language is not unique.

Comment: Than I misunderstood your question, sorry. But if so, it's better to use two queries: `select count(*) from langs where name = "search_lang"` and depending on return value preform full select of values with lang you need or default.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on the logic from yko's answer, this separates out the determination of which language to use, then returns all rows for that language:

```
 SELECT * FROM languages WHERE id = '1' AND lang IN
   (SELECT lang FROM languages WHERE id = '1' AND lang IN ('es', 'en')
    ORDER BY lang = 'es' LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Since the subquery is limited by 1, we can replace `lang IN` with `lang =`, right?
Like this
`SELECT * FROM languages WHERE id = '1' AND lang =
   (SELECT lang FROM languages WHERE id = '1' AND lang IN ('es', 'en')
    ORDER BY lang = 'es' LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Yes, that looks logically correct -- as long as SQlite recognizes that LIMIT 1 returns a scalar value, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your primary key constraint, both rows won't have the same id value (1 in your example), so passing `WHERE id='1'` is likely your problem.  If no two rows have the same `lang` value you can omit the `id` clause entirely, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM Languages WHERE lang='en'
```

Comment: Obviously, they *do* have the same value, since that's what the OP specified.  This looks like a localization table in which `id` specifies a phrase or phrases and `lang` the translation.  Furthermore, your query will *never* return the preferred set of rows (the ones in spanish).

Comment: According to the OP: `id - (primary key, unique)` seems to suggest that its unique, and a primary key constraint would dictate that there are no duplicates.  But he keeps changing his question so lets see where it goes in the next 20 mins.

Comment: Hey, you're right!  I missed the PK definition.  With the PK in place, the whole question makes no sense — you'll never need more than the id in the WHERE clause to get a single row.